A question about compactness and polytopes
I saw a statement as follow:

Let $A$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $P\subset A$ a closed
subset of $A$. By compactness, to prove that $P$ is a polytope, it
sufffices to work locally about a point $x\in P$.

I don't understand the meaning of "work locally about $x$", and how does the compactness guarantees that we can just prove the statement locally?
Thanks in advance.

What's your definition of polytope?

@Thorgott A polytope is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is cut out by finitely many half-spaces. It is also can be defined as the convex hull of a finite set of points.

The fact that one equivalent definition is as a convex hull makes the hope for it being local hard to believe to me: anything like the union of two disjoint convex polytopes should "locally" look like a polytope by any reasonable definition of "locally", while it is clearly not convex.

could it be your definition of polytope is different, and in fact allows nonconvex or even disconnected topological spaces?

@teovvv Sorry for the delay respond. You are right. The question originally arise from a more specific context, not from pure convex geometry. In that context, $P$ is convex at first.

As was discussed in comments, if we work with OP's definition of polytope as the convex hull of finitely many points, then the result OP wants makes sense only if we assume A to CONVEX on top of compact.
If we do that, I think one can argue as follows:
Let $P$ be a compact convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that around each point $x \in P$, there is a compact neighbourhood $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $U \cap P$ is convex. Then it is a convex hull of a finite subset $ Y_U \subset U\cap P$. By compactness, we can choose finitely many neighbourhoods $U_j$ such that the sets $int(U_j\cap P)$ cover $P$ (the interior being taken for the topology on $P$). We define $Y:\bigcap_j Y_{U_j}$
Clearly the convex hull of $Y$ is contained in $P$ since this last is convex. Conversely,
$$Conv(Y) \supset \bigcup_j Conv(Y_{U_j})= \bigcup_j (U_j\cap P)\supset \bigcup_j int(U_j\cap P) =P$$
and you won.
